# How can I implement a Material Design Expand/Collapse List in HTML?

Tags: html, css, material-design

As suggested in the title I am trying to implement an expandable list but on the navigation  drawer. I am trying to do this in plain HTML and CSS. Here's what it should look like [Expandable List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xy0x.png)

I proceeded with attempting to create a page with a navigation drawer and in that have a list of pages. Please find the related code

```
 <div class="mdc-drawer__content">
          <ul class="mdc-list">
            <a class="mdc-list-item" href="#">
              <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>

              <span class="mdc-list-item__text">
                <span class="mdc-list-item__primary-text"> Home </span>
                <span class="mdc-list-item__secondary-text"
                  >Dashboard
                </span>
                <span class="mdc-list-item__secondary-text">Submenu1 </span>
              </span>
            </a>
            <a class="mdc-list-item" href="/admin/account.html">
              <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>

              <span class="mdc-list-item__text mdc-list-item__primary-text"
                >Submenu2</span
              >
            </a>
            

          </ul>
        </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/26pq48Lv/11/

I wish to see The links Submenu1 and Submenu2 in expanded list of Item1 which could collapse.

Comment: Your result seems fine, what is the actual problem?

Comment: do you have a baseline of code which you can't implement or are are looking for any advices before starting?

Comment: Did you try to make it by yourself? If yes, then kindly share the code with us so we can help you, stackoverflow is meant for solving your queries and not for getting ready-made code.

Comment: @aszen I got the above pic on the documentation page https://material.io/components/lists#types. I could not find a way to implement this in plain html with mdc classes

Comment: @simo54 I am looking for advice on how to proceed for the above as I didn't find any documentation surrounding the same

Comment: @RudyTheWebDev Sry about not sharing any related code, Here's my failed attempt at implementing Expandable list in HTML using MDC, https://jsfiddle.net/26pq48Lv/11/. I want the List parts Submenu1 and Submenu2 to be in expandable list.